# Is that possible to play default notification sound of a device in flutter?

Tags: flutter

Is that possible to play default notification sound of a device (for both android and ios) in flutter?
I tried `SystemSound.play(SystemSoundType.click);`, it doesn't do anything. thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [flutter_ringtone_player](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_ringtone_player) plugin to play the default notification sound for both Android and iOS platforms as follows:

```
FlutterRingtonePlayer.playNotification();
```